# Using groupby in a subquery? Trying to find the revenue sum of all retailer, product pairs on the first day the product was bought

Tags: sql

As the title said, I am saying to find the revenue sum for each retailer, product pair on the first day the product was bought by a specific retailer.

I tried replacing the subquery with a date and it worked. I tried running the subquery by itself, and it also worked. But when I run the entire code, it doesn't work and does not give a descriptive suggestion for the error. I have researched for about an hour, and I still cant figure this out... May someone point me to the right direction? Or explain what I am doing wrong?

```
 SELECT SUM(product_sales) AS gmv
    FROM transactions.order_item_summary
    WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      AND retailer_id IS NOT NULL
      AND product_id IS NOT NULL
      AND order_date = (SELECT MIN(order_date)
                        FROM transactions.order_item_summary
                        WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
                          AND retailer_id IS NOT NULL
                          AND product_id IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY retailer_id, product_id)
    GROUP BY retailer_id, product_id;
```

Comment: What is the **exact, complete error message** that you're getting? It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You should add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using when you [edit] to add that error message. Also, from the SO Meta FAQ: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your query.

Comment: And also tag the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the Error message or what Database type you are querying, the best I can do is suggest a change based on a line that looks odd ..

I think you need to remove the `GROUP BY` statement in your nested select

```
GROUP BY retailer_id, product_id
```

The query will instead look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(product_sales) AS gmv
    FROM transactions.order_item_summary
    WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      AND retailer_id IS NOT NULL
      AND product_id IS NOT NULL
      AND order_date = (SELECT MIN(order_date)
                        FROM transactions.order_item_summary
                        WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
                          AND retailer_id IS NOT NULL
                          AND product_id IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY retailer_id, product_id;
```

When the query states `order_date =`  SQL expects the nested select statement on the right side of the `=` to return only one result. I'm guessing that your nested select statement is returning multiple results (due to the use of `GROUP BY`) and that is causing an error

Or if you need to keep that `GROUP BY` consider using `IN` rather than `=`
There's more documentation on `IN` here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT SUM(product_sales) AS gmv
    FROM transactions.order_item_summary
    WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      AND retailer_id IS NOT NULL
      AND product_id IS NOT NULL
      AND order_date IN (SELECT MIN(order_date)
                        FROM transactions.order_item_summary
                        WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
                          AND retailer_id IS NOT NULL
                          AND product_id IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY retailer_id, product_id)
    GROUP BY retailer_id, product_id;
```